# How to append the Data to Dictionary from Data Table?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a Data Table having two columns.How to add my data table row into my dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, object> lst = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 try
   {
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
      lst.Add(row["Inuse"].ToString(), row["Inuse"] as string);
        lst.Add(row["Time"].ToString(), row["Time"] as string);
     }

    }
     catch (Exception ex)
       {
        throw ex;
        }
return lst;
```

But I can't able to add my rows to dictionary.suggest some ideas .

Comment: If you want to add column Time as key and Inuse as value in dictionary then write code as : `lst.Add(row["Time"].ToString(), row["Inuse"] as string);`

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(
                    row => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .ToDictionary(
                        column => column.ColumnName as string, 
                        column => row["Time"] as object
                             )
                        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. @ Mohit Shrivastava

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object> lst = new Dictionary<string, object>();
try
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //Adds time as key and Inuse as value in dictionary
        lst.Add(row["Time"].ToString(), row["Inuse"] as string);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: If i want to add another item to dictionary then how can I add?

Comment: lst.Add(row["Name"].ToString(), row["Time"].ToString(), row["Inuse"] as string);   I tried but it showing some error.